# How to remove folder name from URL in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

Hi I have just shifted my website to new hosting parter with multiple website hosting plan. Every things are working fine except one issue with url. As for different websites there are diffrent folders where i upload my website files these will cause url issues. like :

My previous URL : www.abc.com

After uploading www.abc.com/folderName  So I would like to remove folderName from the url. I have googled to many documents regarding web.config url rewrites but none of them are working. Kindly help to remove folderName from the URL. (Note I am also using URL Routing in global.asax if possible to remove folder name using global.asax it will work for me too)

Thanks

Comment: You can set the default folder path in your hosting environment.

Comment: already set but folder name is now concatenated to my URL

Comment: What IIS version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by following steps

1) Used Global.asax to forefully redirect my users to my website without folder name.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.RedirectPermanent("http://www.myDomain.com");
    }
```

2) I have changed my relative URLs to Absolute URLs

```
Changed ~/contact to http://www.myDomain.com/contact
```